# Maximal regularity heat equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, parabolic-pde, linear-pde, heat-equation

Considering the heat equation on the flat torus $\mathbf{T}^d$, we have the maximal regularity estimate
\begin{align*}
\forall \varphi\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{T}^d),\quad \|\Delta \varphi\|_p \lesssim_p \|\partial_t \varphi - \Delta \varphi\|_p,\qquad (\star) 
\end{align*}
the laplacian acting on the space variable only and the norm refering to $L^p(\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{T}^d)$ for some $1<p<\infty$. I thought that from this specific formulation on compactly supported test functions, one could recover the local version of this result that is, whenever $\varphi$ is smooth and vanishes at $t=0$, there holds
\begin{align*}
\|\Delta \varphi\|_{T,p} \lesssim_p \|\partial_t \varphi - \Delta \varphi\|_{T,p}, \qquad (\star\star)
\end{align*}
where this time the norm refers to $L^p(Q_T)$ with $Q_T:=(0,T)\times\mathbf{T}^d$, $\lesssim_p$ **being independent** of  the final time $T>0$.

However, when trying to localize the first estimate with some test function $\theta\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbf{R})$, there's an extra term that I am not able to handle correctly. I thought I could find some answer in this [expository paper](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Esalamon/PREPRINTS/parabolic.pdf) which states a similar compact-support like estimate (but in the whole physical space instead of the torus), however on page 6 the Theorem 1.1 is used on the function $v$ which precisely is not compactly supported in time (so I don't see this as a direct consequence of Theorem 1.1). The painful fact is that if one localizes $f:=\partial_t \varphi-\Delta \varphi$, the corresponding solution of the heat equation **is not** compactly supported. On the other hand, if one localizes $\varphi$ directly then there's an extra term which gives a Dirac mass when the test function is sent to $\mathbf{1}_{[0,T]}$.

So my question is : can $(\star\star)$ be easily recovered from $(\star)$ directly or, for some reason, there's a real difficulty and estimates $(\star\star)$ have to be obtained directly ?

Comment: Let me comment on a similar situation where the same problem appears. Assuming $(*)$ on test functions on the whole space $R^{d+1}$ one wants a localized version in $(-\infty, T)\times R^d$. The direct approach does not work: instead I first extend $(*)$ to the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}_p$ and show solvability for $u+u_t-\Delta u=f$ in $R^{d+1}$. Then I show slovability for the same problem in $(-\infty,T)\times R^d$ just extending $f$ for $t \geq T$, solving in the whole space  and inherit the estimates from the whole space.

Comment: Thanks @GiorgioMetafune. For some reason I kept on complicating things more than necessary !